# Best Way to Center Text in Form React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am wondering what is the best way to center the Form.Label components inside my form. I am new to React and Bootstrap.

```
<Form>
        <Styles>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

Comment: try `<center>` tag like this `<center><Form.Label>Email</Form.Label></center>`

Comment: try `<Form.Label float="center">Email</Form.Label>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that adding "text-center" as your className in your Form.Label component should be enough.

```
  <Form.Label className="text-center">Email</Form.Label>
```

You might not see the label "really" centered in the screen because of the width it has, but if you set a width, for example, of 100%, it should center in your screen.

For example,

```
<Form.Label className="text-center" style={{width: "100%"}}>Email</Form.Label>
```

If yo want to check the final result, it's here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dubinsky-n3von?fontsize=14

[image: Edit agitated-dubinsky-n3von]